# Is it possible to manage VSCode extension per language project

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use 3 languages (TS, C#, and python) so it is possible to load extensions based on the project language instead of loading all extensions. I know there's workplace for it, but it still manually enable/disable. So could we automatically manage extension based on project language?

ex: when I developed a React app, it automatically loaded eslint, prettier, react snippet, etc. Or when I developed a dotnet app, it automatically loaded C#, auto-using, etc

Comment: how should VSC know which extension should be used for a language, you have to pick the selection by enable it per workspace

Comment: Nvm. I found it. I only need to create an extension pack that include all extension that i need per language project.

Comment: and all these extensions are stored in ONE directory and always enabled

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line option `--extensions-dir <dir>`, which can be used to specify the directory where extensions are stored.
([https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#:~:text=%2D%2Dextensions%2Ddir%20%3Cdir%3E](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#:%7E:text=%2D%2Dextensions%2Ddir%20%3Cdir%3E))

You can create multiple shortcuts for your different languages:

- `code --extensions-dir c:\vscode\TS_extensions`
- `code --extensions-dir c:\vscode\Csharp_extensions`
- `code --extensions-dir c:\vscode\Phyton_extensions`

P.S: This will not stop you from opening a file in VS Code with the wrong extensions enabled (for example: opening a Python file, and only seeing the Csharp extensions)